# Add class based on current page filename when page is refreshed

Tags: jquery, refresh

I'm using this to add a class based on current page filename without file extension:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    $( "html" ).removeClass();
    $( "html" ).addClass( filename.split('.')[0] );
});
```

It doesn't work when the page is refreshed.

If I change `$(document).ready(function()` to `$(window).on('load', function()`, it doesn't work **until** the page is refreshed.

Comment: I just simulated your issue, you can download the html file here and run open it in your browser https://gist.github.com/joshmoto/45ad0d7ee315e85c9026c4928685fe90 - every time i refresh it works for me

Comment: I ended up stumbling my way into a solution for this problem, but thank you for your interest!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up sorting this by running it as two different functions.